# Google Business Apps (MX records setup) - "been over 48 hours and they still don't point to our servers"

Tags: cpanel, google-apps, mx-record

***Current Problem*** (view image)

Message on "Google Business Apps" gmail setup page.

[image]

---

---

## ***Steps Taken***

I have entered the google mx records into my cpanel area & waited 48 hours.

[image]

***Dot at end***

[image]

***No dot at end***

[image]

***Current Look***

Bottom value is "mydomain.co.nz", which was set by default.
I have set this value as low priority, as indicated.

[image]

---

---

I'm unsure why it is not working.
I'm still receiving my domain emails at my personal gmail account....is this conflicting with my business apps setup?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a programming question and so it is probably not appropriate for StackOverflow. Please post it to the Google Apps Help Forum at: http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/apps